# Is encryption of request parameters needed on form submission when using HTTPS?

Tags: java, security, https

I am using HTTPS protocol on my website. I am not using any encryption mechanism on request parameters are going (username, password, a/c details etc). It is Ok?

Answer (score 2):

The request parameters aren't visible to any observers between you and the server. You don't need to encrypt anything yourself.

Just make sure the form is passed as a POST, as the URL may be stored in logs or otherwise be seen on the server or client end.

Comment: But there is some possibility that observer (Man in Middle) can put some fake certificate in between client and server. Like proxy tools work (BurpSuite, Charles, OSWAP ZAP etc). DO you have any idea regarding this?

Comment: You can't put a "fake certificate" in between without anyone noticing. That would render SSL completely useless.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents: do not copy request parameters directly on to HTML objects likewise by using scriptlet <% = request.getParameter("some_param")%>